# Is it possible to have polymorphic to polymorphic relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to define a relationship where multiple different models can be related to multiple different models.

I've got schema for pivot table:

```
Schema::create('triggerables', static function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->morphs('triggered_by');
  $table->morphs('triggerable');
});
```

model for that table:

```
class Triggerable extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'triggerables';

    public function triggerable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo('triggerable');
    }

    public function triggeredBy(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo('triggered_by');
    }
}
```

relationship for pivot table in other model:

```
public function testTriggerable(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Triggerable::class, 'triggered_by');
}
```

but relationship returns pivot table itself is it possible to use that table to get all of the different models attached to it?

Comment: 1) Pivot tables generally don't have an `id` column, since the data in them changes constantly, and it's unlikely you'll ever need to do `Pivot::find(1)`, since you'd search by the id(s) of `ModelA` or `ModelB`. 2) Your pivot table only has a single `id`, but the whole point of a pivot is to connect 2 Models by their `id`, like `model_a_id` and `model_b_id`. You _might_ be able to accomplish this using Polymorphism (I can't say I've seen a use case for this), but your current database structure is not a proper `many-to-many`.